# Google Drive API copy a file in team drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am writing a function to copy a folder in my Google Drive to another folder. The function works for folders that are in the regular Drive space. However, when I run it on a team drive folder, I am getting the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Code/catpython/driveapi_utils.py", line 232, in <module>
    test_copy_folder()
  File "C:/Code/catpython/driveapi_utils.py", line 221, in test_copy_folder
    copy_folder(service, src='xxxxxx',
  File "C:/Code/catpython/driveapi_utils.py", line 211, in copy_folder
    copy_folder(service, file.get('id'), file.get('name'), dst_parent_id, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Code/catpython/driveapi_utils.py", line 201, in copy_folder
    fileId=clone.get("id"),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

My code is as follows:

```
def copy_folder(service, src, src_name, dst, **kwargs):
    """
    Copies a folder. It will create a new folder in dst with the same name as src,
    and copies the contents of src into the new folder
    src: Source folder's id
    dst: Destination folder's id that the source folder is going to be copied to
    """

    page_token = None
    while True:
        response = service.files().list(q="'%s' in parents and trashed = false" % src,
                                        supportsAllDrives=True,
                                        spaces='drive',
                                        fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType)',
                                        pageToken=page_token,
                                        includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
                                        ).execute()
        dst_parent_id = create_folder(service, src_name, dst, **kwargs)
        for file in response.get('files', []):
            # Process change
            print('Found file: %s (%s, %s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id'), file.get('mimeType')))
            if not file.get('mimeType') == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
                clone = None
                try:
                    clone = service.files().copy(fileId=file.get('id'),
                                         body={'title': 'copiedFile',
                                               'parents': [{'kind': "drive#fileLink",
                                                            'id': dst_parent_id}],
                                               'supportsAllDrives': True,
                                               }).execute()
                except HttpError as httpe:
                    pass
                try:
                    service.files().update(
                        fileId=clone.get("id"),
                        addParents=dst_parent_id,
                        removeParents=src,
                        fields="id, parents",
                        supportsAllDrives=True
                    ).execute()
                except HttpError as httpe:
                    pass
            else:
                print('drilling into %s' % file.get('name'))
                copy_folder(service, file.get('id'), file.get('name'), dst_parent_id, **kwargs)
        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if page_token is None:
            break
```

I debugged the code and I think the copy api threw an error:

```
<HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1n7h04M6Rpz3m2J6MGZq8trlnADEBFLrK/copy?alt=json returned "File not found: 1n7h04M6Rpz3m2J6MGZq8trlnADEBFLrK.". Details: "File not found: 1n7h04M6Rpz3m2J6MGZq8trlnADEBFLrK.">
```

However the file does exist and the same code works on files in my personal space. I have full access to the team drive, as you can see from the code, I am able to query files and create folders in it.

What could be missing? Or is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your question, it seems that `service.files().list` occurs no error. Using this information, from `fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType)'` of `service.files().list`, it is fou.nd that you are using `service` as Drive API v3.
- When you are using Drive API v3, your request of `service.files().copy` is required to be modified.

  1. `title` is `name`.
  2. `'parents': [{'kind': "drive#fileLink", 'id': dst_parent_id}]` is `'parents': [dst_parent_id]`.
- And also, `'supportsAllDrives': True` is not included in the request body. I think that this is the reason of your error message.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
clone = service.files().copy(fileId=file.get('id'),
                     body={'title': 'copiedFile',
                           'parents': [{'kind': "drive#fileLink",
                                        'id': dst_parent_id}],
                           'supportsAllDrives': True,
                           }).execute()
```

To:

```
clone = service.files().copy(fileId=file.get('id'),
                             body={'name': 'copiedFile',
                                   'parents': [dst_parent_id],
                                   },
                             supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy)

Comment: Thanks! that solved my problem. The main cause should be as you said, the supportsAllDrives parameter was not set correctly.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the `'supportsAllDrives': True` flag. This solved my similar  issue.

Comment: @dj_thossi Thank you for your comment. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.